# Has Zariel been redeemed in the timeline of D&D Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, dnd-adventurers-league, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

In Baldur's Gate: Descent Into Avernus, one of the main possible endings features the redemption of the archdevil Zariel. However, I understand that Adventurers League is run as its own ongoing campaign with its own timeline. In the story of D&D Adventurers League, has Zariel been redeemed?

Comment: Can you point to where AL states they still determine a majority outcome of all play-throughs to establish a canonical stroy line? From what I could find, they did so in the early seasons, but I could find nothing published in this regard anywhere for more recent seasons.

Answer (score 5):

I checked [DDAL09-20 Where Devils Fear to Tread](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/321069/DDAL0920-Where-Devils-Fear-to-Tread), the last adventure of Avernus Rising. The adventure mentions Zariel 12 times, but never indicates or implies that she's been redeemed. As to where she is, it only has this to say:

> ! Zariel herself is nowhere to be seen. Nothing
> could have kept her from defending Avernus, but the
> battle stretches beyond the horizon so it is likely that her
> attention is elsewhere—such as wherever Yeenoghu’s
> vassal Doresain, the King of Ghouls, has taken the
> field—when it is sorely needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Zariel's actions could be different in every game.  Not all games redeem Zariel.  The three main headings of options in Chapter 5 are:  Redeeming Zariel, Zariel's Wrath [fighting her], and Serving Zariel [helping her rule Avernus].

Since every AL completion of *Baldur's Gate: Descent Into Avernus* can have a different outcome, it is not possible to have a single Adventurers' League timeline.

Comment: Is there any evidence or quote that you can point to support your answer?

Comment: @Ruse There are 3 possible outcomes at the end of the book: Redeeming, Serving, or Defeating her.  The evidence is in the module, you need to buy it.

Comment: Right, you can still quote excerpts of the module to support your answer. Eitherway, the OP believes that the Adventurer's League has it's own timeline and they want to know whether Zariel was redeemed in *that* timeline, so merely stating that "not all games redeem Zariel" doesn't really answer the question. Can you edit your answer to clarify your point and address the question?

Comment: I think there was a policy by AL in earlier seasons to tally up the outcomes from different play-throughs, to arrive at a majority outcome and "official" time line. Not sure if they still do that, though.